# Database of labeled hyperspectral imagery

Tags: geospatial, images

(Cross-post from [GIS StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244915/database-of-labeled-hyperspectral-imagery).)

Are there any datasets of hyperspectral imagery that can be used for AI training and classification, comparable to ImageNet? The Universitat de Valencia has one listed on their site, HyperLabelMe, but it seems to have been taken down.

Comment: link to listing?

Comment: isp.uv.es/data_rs.html

Comment: so going off your conversation in the gis post, can it be lidar? eros? or rather can you explain what hyperspectral is/means to you?

Comment: [Please do not crosspost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Remove one of your questions.

Comment: @JanDoggen yeah i was actually confused as to where to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[University of Alaska has some test datasets](http://www.hyperspectral.alaska.edu/resources_data_products.html)
[USGS Spectroscopy Lab FTP](ftp://ftpext.cr.usgs.gov/pub/cr/co/denver/speclab/pub/)
[Spec Lab has tutorials with small datasets](https://speclab.cr.usgs.gov/)